# Using group of regular expressions in java

Tags: java, regex

i'm writing a program which should change text file with regex. I have
a few commands, and they are working in e.g NotePad++. I want now the same commands in java to make it faster. Can it be caused by the way it saves and reads the file?

```
private List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>(10000000);

// read original file to an ArrayList
public String[] readOriginalFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String line = null;
    while (((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)){
        lines.add(line);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
}

 public void replaceWordsOne() {
    ArrayList<String> lns = new ArrayList<String>(10000000);
    for (String ln : lines) {
        lns.add(ln.replaceAll("^(\\[.*?\\])\\s+(\\[.*?\\])\\s(\\[.*?\\]\\s){1,}(\\[.*?\\])", "\1\t\2\t\4\t"));
    }
    lines.clear();
    lines = lns;
}

public void writeToNewFileOne(String FinalDirectory) throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(FinalDirectory);
    for (String str : lines) {
        writer.write(str +"\n");
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: Repeated use of a raw regular expression will destroy performance. Use a [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) - compile once, use forever.

Comment: Performance isn't so important here. Now I have the impression that it may be due to something else. I think that regex and groups needed whole text not single line. How can i load whole file?

Comment: You have said in your own question that you want it to run faster, yet now you're saying performance is not important? Decide what you want to do and then reformulate your question please

Comment: Java program could by faster than my manual work :)

Answer (score 1):

i think that the main cause is this line:

```
private List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>(10000000);
```

in java arraylist are dynamic resize arrays, that's means that you don't need to initialize the list with elements.

should be like this:

```
private List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: No, it doesn't make difference.

Comment: ok, try to use StringBuilder instead a list of Strings like this:    StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder(); lines.append(line); // to add new lines.  reference link: https://www.javatpoint.com/StringBuilder-class

Comment: ok,i see that you use a list of strings and replace the characters with a regular expression line by line and the save this in another list, i think that there could be the bottle neck in your code, so when you replace the characters do this for the entire string instead 'line by line' way.